# How to use UWP functionality from a .Net 6 WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, .net-6.0

I have a WPF application built for **.Net Framework**.

It references a UWP library for doing things like using Start-Tiles etc.

I'm now converting this WPF application to **.Net 6**, but can't seem to find a way to call UWP methods from it.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application that targets and runs on the .NET Framework cannot consume a library that is compiled for UWP, like for example a library that was created using the `Class Library (Universal Windows)` template in Visual Studio.

You may use [Windows Runtime APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) in your .NET Framework app though but that's another thing.

If you want to share code between a .NET Framework application and a UWP app, your project that contains the shared code should target [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077). It can then be consumed from all applications that target platforms that is compatible with the version of the .NET Standard you are targeting in your class library.

Comment: It seems you are correct. My .Net Framework application references a .Net Framework library that has references to `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract` etc. How do I get this in .Net 6 ?

Comment: OK. I now see that's included in your link to the Windows Runtime APIs. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But it looks like for .Net 6 we need to use the `Target Framework Moniker`. Or does that `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` option still work for .Net 6 ?

Comment: In .NET 5 and later the package reference should be replaced by a TFM.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!